# How to stay within the bounds of memory

Tags: multithreading, scala, out-of-memory

I am trying to run a program to calculate the missing 4th value in an equation and I keep running out of memory. Is there a way to stay in memory, or do I need to format my code differently?

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._

val p1=1<<56
val p2=1<<52 
val p3=0<<32
(1L to 100000000).par.foreach( (x: Long) =>{
    if(((p1|p2)|(p3|x)).toLong==76561198036298569L)
    {
        println("FOUND: "+x)
        break
    }
})
```

Comment: If you were to look at the bits of that number, the value of `x` would be fairly obvious.

Comment: Is this just an example problem with a large loop, or are you really trying to solve that equation?

Comment: `76561198036298569L` is `0b100010000000000000000000100000100100010000010101101001001` in binary. All you are doing is bitwise-or-ing the values, so you can find the binary value of `x` by removing the 52nd and 56th bits, which leaves you with `0b100000100100010000010101101001001`.

Comment: Yes, this is just an example.

Comment: `1<<56` gives Int result, not Long. At least Repl evaluates this as `Int = 16777216`, which is `1 << 24`. You need to write 1L << x, if you want such value.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options (and similar ones have already been suggested); you don't have to necessarily store an integer number in an integer object; you could rather store them as sequence of bits or even in a container e.g. a List (slow due to the linked list nature of scala lists, I would suggest BitSet or HashSet (for the constant and eC time complexity).

TLDR; you can represent unimaginably large numbers by just storing them differently for the cost of execution speed without changing the code **much**.

Comment: I do not understand how this answers the question. Long seems big enough to store numbers here. The memory is consumed someplace else.

Comment: If I stored the values differently how would this fix my memory problems? I might be able to store a few more values, but I am looking for a way to store as many as possible in memory then stop and keep filling up memory as operations complete,